# Android media player works with some url but not with others

Tags: java, android

My code is working fine if I use this URL

> http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hosannatelugu.mp3

But if I tried to use this URL then I got the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
//after some lines


start called in state 0
   error (-38, 0)
```

This is the second URL that I used

> http://hcservices.byethost4.com/hosannatelugu.mp3

If you open the file you'll notice that both are the same thing. Earlier I thought the `.mp3` file is corrupted but it's not!

I guess issue is related to the host or something else but I'm running out of the idea.

Here's my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button play;
    Button stop;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://hcservices.byethost4.com/hosannatelugu.mp3");
                MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                try {
                    String a = "http://hcservices.byethost4.com/hosannatelugu.mp3";
                    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                    mPlayer.setDataSource(a);

                    mPlayer.prepare();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mPlayer.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna copy some documentation from the Android site here. Maybe it will help you.

> Playing from a remote URL via HTTP streaming looks like this

```
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Since your code already looks like that, I am assuming your problem is this additional note.

> Note: If you're passing a URL to stream an online media file, the file must be capable of progressive download.

So, if that first link works, but the second one doesn't, that would mean the second host does not support "progressive download." And that is a problem with the server, not your application or code.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Comment: and how to make my URL "capable of progressive download."

Comment: As I stated in my post, use a different server. There is nothing you can do to control that. You may be able to detect if a server supports progressive download, but I don't know how to do that immediately